# JQuery: .remove() does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

Here is my html and codes :

```
  <div id="rptCategoryProducts">
    <ul class="productsUl">
    </ul>
   </div>
```

removing scritp :

```
         $("#btnFilter").click(function () {

            $(".productsUl li").each(function () {
                this.remove();
            });

            currentPage = 0;
            InfiniteScroll(0, 1000);
        });
```

adding script:

```
 $(".productsUl").append("<li>" + productInnerHtml + "</li>");
```

But it doesn't remove and also when I watch the steps in Mozilla Firebug I saw it stops after `this.remove();` line. 
Do you have suggestion?

Comment: Replace `this` by `$(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or even simpler:

```
$(".productsUl li").remove();
```

;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$(this)` to refer to the `li` element

```
$("#btnFilter").click(function () {
  $(".productsUl li").each(function () {
          $(this).remove();
   });

   currentPage = 0;
   InfiniteScroll(0, 1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gwbmw/

Answer (score 1):

When you loop through a jQuery object using `each`, you get the elements themselves, not each element wrapped in a jQuery object. You need to wrap each element in a jQuery object to use the `remove` method:

```
$(".productsUl li").each(function () {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

However, you don't even need to loop through the elements, just use the `remove` method on the jQuery object containing all the elements:

```
$(".productsUl li").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `$(this)` instead of `this` -

```
$(".productsUl li").each(function () {
        $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoud try this:

```
$(this).remove();
```

instead of

```
this.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing '$'. Try:

```
 $(".productsUl li").each(function () {
               $(this).remove();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

In `each` callback, `this` points to the dom element reference not to the jquery object reference. So you need to get the jquery object reference of the item before calling `remove()`

```
$(".productsUl li").each(function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

It can be done much easily

```
$(".productsUl > li").remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange. It works for me. look at this test:

```
[link]http://jsfiddle.net/bwqwD/
```